# PHP округление к тыс/млн/млрд

Tags: php

Помогите округлить число 1200 к 1.2К а например 1200000 к 1.2M

Answer (score 0):

Функция по огруглению числа с постфиксом

```
<?php
    function formatToHuman($number)
    {        
            if ($number < 1000) {
                 return sprintf('%d', $number);
            }

            if ($number < 1000000) {
                $number = $number / 1000;
                return $newVal = number_format($number,1) . 'k';
            }

            if ($number >= 1000000 && $number < 1000000000) {
                $number = $number / 1000000;
                return $newVal = number_format($number,1) . 'M';
            }

            if ($number >= 1000000000 && $number < 1000000000000) {
                $number = $number / 1000000000;
                return $newVal = number_format($number,1) . 'B';
            }

            return sprintf('%d%s', floor($number / 1000000000000), 'T+');        
    }

echo formatToHuman(123333433); // 123.3M
echo formatToHuman(12400); // 12.4K
?>
```

Можете тут проверить: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f44146639e09c348de52681d6dff065953b2e6ed

Comment: Скопировал и вставил ваш код в свой файл функций и все 500 ошибка

Comment: Наверное у вас старый PHP, изменил код. Можете проверить?